# Java Unicode CJK | Programmatically distinguish fallback chars

Tags: java, unicode, fonts

Hello I am trying to print some CJK unicode characters to a .txt file based on their unicode code number.

Is there a way to distinguish between the fallback characters (box with four digits) and the "printable" characters? (i.e. when the CJK characters appear as they should look like)

I would like to end up with something like

```
if(!isFallback(myChar)) { printToFile(); }

private boolean isFallback(char c) { // return true if the system will resort to fallback characters}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the [canDisplay()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29) method do what you're looking for?

It might not - especially if you really are talking about using the fallback-font display behaviour of the Java logical fonts (which your question implies you are).

Are you running this on OSX, by chance?
If the canDisplay() method is not what you're looking for - you'll need to give a bit more info about what you're doing - platform, JDK version, font you've selected (or none?), example code ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be best).